# Itexpdf PdfContentByte special character

Tags: itext

I'm using ItextPdf 5.

How I can add special characters to my document via PdfContentByte ?

there is my code :

```
 public void addFlag(PdfWriter writer, BaseFont baseFont, Font font) {
        String mytext = "My flag : \u2691";
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.setFontAndSize(baseFont, font.getSize());
        cb.beginText();
        cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, mytext, 10, 50, 0f);
        cb.endText();
        cb.stroke();
    }
```

Comment: What do you pass as `basefont` and is `\u2691` defined in this font. If it is, your code will work. If it isn't, the character won't be rendered. Since you are asking this question, chances are that the latter is true. The solution? Use a font that supports `\u2691`.

Comment: Logic ! Thank you Bruno